# Increasing number of returned documents from ctx.payload loop in watcher api - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my watcher, I am iterating over returned documents via the `{{#ctx.payload.hits.hits}} ... {{/ctx.payload.hits.hits}}` notation. It is working properly however only returning the top 10 documents in the payload. If I have a payload of size > 10, then it will only iterate over the first 10 documents.

Is there any config somewhere in which I can adjust what I imagine the default amount of 10 is to something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [search body request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) may contain a size parameter that specifies the number of documents to retrieve. If this parameter is not set, this value defaults to 10.
Since, The action access the result of the query only, you see only these 10 documents.

In order to retrieve more documents you have to set this parameter to the desired value, e.g., 100 (note that there is an upper bound) in the query portion of the watcher.